# Group objects by property in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to convert this:

```
[
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'banana', type: 'fruit'},
]
```

into this:

```
[
    {type: 'fruit', foods: ['apple', 'banana']},
    {type: 'vegetable', foods: ['potato']}
]
```

using javascript or underscore

Comment: @Harley It's best to show what you've tried. Succinct is not as important as showing effort. It's not just an idle request, either--seeing where you are with it gives us a better shot at creating something exactly at the needed level.

Comment: @ErikE Alternatively, this is a nice and simple question that has high googability, with no such nonsense as failed and convoluted attempts of a solution. This is the type of question that will get the most up-votes because its generic and the answer will be as well, ultimately benefitting everyone.

Comment: @SSHThis To each his own perspective, though some perspectives may be more in line with reality than others. I think you will find once you participate on this site longer that showing effort is an important part of the community's values...

Comment: @ErikE No need to be snarky ...  again

Comment: @SSHThis I have a factual disagreement with you, that is all!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Assuming the original list is contained in a variable named `list`:

```
_
.chain(list)
.groupBy('type')
.map(function(value, key) {
    return {
        type: key,
        foods: _.pluck(value, 'food')
    }
})
.value();
```

Comment: Who needs lengthy SQL when you have underscore + mongoDB!?

Comment: Whoever needs their code to perform well and avoid doing data query operations on  RAM and wants to make use of the database server.

Answer (score 17):

Without using underscore:

```js
var origArr = [
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'banana', type: 'fruit'}
];

/*[
    {type: 'fruit', foods: ['apple', 'banana']},
    {type: 'vegetable', foods: ['potato']}
]*/

function transformArr(orig) {
    var newArr = [],
        types = {},
        i, j, cur;
    for (i = 0, j = orig.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = orig[i];
        if (!(cur.type in types)) {
            types[cur.type] = {type: cur.type, foods: []};
            newArr.push(types[cur.type]);
        }
        types[cur.type].foods.push(cur.food);
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(transformArr(origArr));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/nSLua/3/

Credit goes to **@ErikE** for improving/reducing my original code to help with redundancy I had :)

Comment: Suggestion: put `newArr.push(types[cur.type]);` inside your `if` block and remove the second `for` loop entirely.

Comment: @ErikE Yeah, I'm already refactoring. I know the double loop isn't good, so I went back. Hold on, maybe what I'm doing is what you're saying.

Comment: @ErikE I think it took a little more than what you suggested, but I already forget what it used to look like. It seems to work, and doesn't require 2 loops, so it seems fine :)

Comment: The index indirection is not needed. I find the new code awkward. Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/nSLua/3/).

Comment: @ErikE Ahh yes, I'm fooled again. I forget that doing it that way, the new object is pushed by reference (which I didn't realize), so you can modify the original (in `types`) and it will be reflected in `newArr`. Thanks for pointing that out! Though I'd hardly call my old code awkward...it made sense as a "lookup" to me at least :)

Comment: I frankly thought your idea of using an object to keep track of the pieces was a great idea. There was just implementing it efficiently to work out. And yes, the trick is that objects in JavaScript are true objects and are accessed by reference.

Comment: @ErikE Haha well I appreciate it, and appreciate the suggestions. For some reason, I thought `push` might act differently and copy it =/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly different but more generic version of @Ian's answer

**Caveat**: the result is slightly different from the OP requirement, but others like me who stumble on this question might benefit from a more generic answer IMHO

```
var origArr = [
   {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
   {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
   {food: 'banana', type: 'fruit'}
];

function groupBy(arr, key) {
        var newArr = [],
            types = {},
            newItem, i, j, cur;
        for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
            cur = arr[i];
            if (!(cur[key] in types)) {
                types[cur[key]] = { type: cur[key], data: [] };
                newArr.push(types[cur[key]]);
            }
            types[cur[key]].data.push(cur);
        }
        return newArr;
}

console.log(groupBy(origArr, 'type'));
```

You can find a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ObiOne86/nSLua/46/)

Comment: Hi there. This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you! -- I think it would be a good idea to show what `console.log` prints out.

Comment: Unused variable newItem and j. Why?

Answer (score 3):

An ES6 solution to this old question:

Iterate using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and collect the items by group into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Use spread to convert the [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) back into array:

```js
const data = [
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'banana', type: 'fruit'},
];

const result = [...data.reduce((hash, { food, type }) => {
  const current = hash.get(type) || { type, foods: [] };
  
  current.foods.push({ food });
  
  return hash.set(type, current);
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var foods = [
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'banana', type: 'fruit'}
];

var newFoods = _.chain( foods ).reduce(function( memo, food ) {
  memo[ food.type ] = memo[ food.type ] || [];
  memo[ food.type ].push( food.food );
  return memo;
}, {}).map(function( foods, type ) {
    return {
        type: type,
        foods: foods
    };
}).value();
```

http://jsbin.com/etaxih/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can group array of objects by one of fields with Alasql library. This example compact arrays exactly as in your example:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT type, ARRAY(food) AS foods FROM ? GROUP BY type',[food]);
```

Try this example [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/yo0nbbvc/1/).

Comment: hi agershum, i tried do what you wrote on an array created fron ajax but wont work result are undefined. But if i try console.log(array[0].property); data in cosolle are ok

Comment: hi agershum, i tried do what you wrote on an array created fron ajax but wont work.
Result are allways undefined. 

example: 

var array=[{
​​
status: undefined

student_id: "32"
​​
student_name: "Marco Bruno"
​​
student_year_id: "2",

status: absent

}
... to 500 record
]


 But if i try console.log(array[0].property); data in cosolle are ok.

I want to count student_id and group by status
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use other ES6 Features such as:

```
function groupArray(arr, groupBy, keepProperty) {
        let rArr = [], i;
        arr.forEach(item => {
            if((i = rArr.findIndex(obj => obj[groupBy] === item[groupBy])) !== -1)
                rArr[i][`${keepProperty}s`].push(item[keepProperty]);
            else rArr.push({
                [groupBy]: item[groupBy],
                [`${keepProperty}s`]: [item[keepProperty]]
            });
        });
        return rArr;
    }

    groupArray(yourArray, 'type', 'food');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.group()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group) method along with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which is currently in Experimental stage. I will suggest you to Check the [`Browser compatibility table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group#browser_compatibility) carefully before using this in production.

Below code snippet will only work in Firefox Nightly as currently `Array.group()` does not have support for any other browsers.

```js
// Input array
const inventory = [
    {food: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
    {food: 'potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {food: 'banana', type: 'fruit'},
];

// Return the object grouped with type property.
const result = inventory.group(({ type }) => type);

// declaring an empty array to store the final results.
const arr = [];

// Iterating the group object to structure the final result.
Object.keys(result).forEach((item, index) => {
  result[item] = result[item].map(({ food }) => food);
  arr.push({
    type: item,
    foods: result[item]
  })
});

// Output
console.log(arr);
```