# Reversing a parent-child relationship using underscore.js/js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, grouping

I have a collection of names, each of which has one or more associated nicknames. I would like to transform this into a collection of nicknames, each of which with one or more names.

Here's an example. I would like to convert this:

```
[
    {id:1, name:'Jack', children:[{nickname:'Jack1'},{nickname:'Jack1'}]},
    {id:2, name:'Sam',  children:[{nickname:'Sam1'}, {nickname:'Sam2'}]},
    {id:3, name:'Tom',  children:[{nickname:'Tom1'}, {nickname:'Tom2'}]},
]
```

Into this:

```
[
    {nickname:'Jack1', obj:[{id:1,name:"Jack"},{id:1,name:'Jack'}]},
    {nickname:'Sam1',  obj:[{id:2,name:'Sam'}]},
    {nickname:'Sam2',  obj:[{id:2,name:'Sam'}]},
    {nickname:'Tom1',  obj:[{id:3,name:'Tom'}]},
    {nickname:'Tom2',  obj:[{id:3,name:'Tom'}]}
]
```

I would prefer to have a solution using underscore, but JavaScript would also be OK.

Comment: What is the relation between the "before" and "after" objects? The "Sam" example I can get, but the "Jack" one makes no sense to me.

Comment: That means group by nickname.

Comment: @WangHongjian, could you please include a sample of the code you've already tried? You will receive more responses if you show that you've already made an attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @WangHongjian, [here's a solution using underscore](http://jsfiddle.net/Q46vA/11/). I'd post as an answer, but unfortunately your question has been closed.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Thanks,your code works well, I also used this method to make it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got what you want.

Since `Jack1` occurs twice in `Jack`, `Jack` has to appear twice in `Jack1`:

```
var a = [
    {id:1, name:'Jack', children:[{nickname:'Jack1'},{nickname:'Jack1'}]},
    {id:2, name:'Sam',  children:[{nickname:'Sam1'}, {nickname:'Sam2'}]},
    {id:3, name:'Tom',  children:[{nickname:'Tom1'}, {nickname:'Tom2'}]},
]

var b = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < a[i].children.length; j++){
        if(b.filter(function(e){
            return e.hasOwnProperty('nickname') && e.nickname == a[i].children[j].nickname;
        }).length === 0){
            b.push({
                nickname: a[i].children[j].nickname,
                obj:[{id:a[i].id, name: a[i].name}]});
        }else{
            for(var k = 0; k < b.length; k++){
                if(b[i].nickname == a[i].children[j].nickname){
                    b[i].obj.push({id:a[i].id, name: a[i].name})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(b);

// Result:
[
    {"nickname": "Jack1", "obj": [{"id": 1, "name": "Jack"},
                                  {"id": 1, "name": "Jack"}]},
    {"nickname": "Sam1",  "obj": [{"id": 2, "name": "Sam"}]},
    {"nickname": "Sam2",  "obj": [{"id": 2, "name": "Sam"}]},
    {"nickname": "Tom1",  "obj": [{"id": 3, "name": "Tom"}]},
    {"nickname": "Tom2",  "obj": [{"id": 3, "name": "Tom"}]}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Is it easy to implement it by underscore? Please see this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887900/group-objects-by-property-in-javascript

Comment: I don't know underscore, but why would you use a library like that when native JS like this works?
Also, since this works, please consider accepting this answer.