# fastest way to group keys with the same numeric value from a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

'Lets say I have an object

```
var obj = {
   apples: 2,
   grapes: 1,
   oranges:2,
   carrots:2,
   potatoes: 4
}
```

how would I write a fast executing function that would return they keys grouped by their values?

```
return {
    "2": ['apples', 'oranges', 'carrots'],
    "4" : ['potatoes'],
    "1" : ['grapes']

}
```

Comment: Really doesn't appear that you even attempted to research this at all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group objects by property in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887900/group-objects-by-property-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple `for..in` to achieve this:

```
var obj = {
   apples: 2,
   grapes: 1,
   oranges:2,
   carrots:2,
   potatoes: 4
};

var result = {};
for(var key in obj) {
   if(!(obj[key] in result)) result[obj[key]] = [];
   result[obj[key]].push(key);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

a quick and dirty function approach is interesting to contrast with the for loop:

```
var obj = {
   apples: 2,
   grapes: 1,
   oranges:2,
   carrots:2,
   potatoes: 4
};

Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a,b,k){ 
  return (a[k=obj[b]]||(a[k]=[])).push(b), a;
},{});
```

there's less build up and tear-down, but the over-all effect is the same and for-loops might be more readable. either way, it's good to at least know about reduce() when facing many-into-one situations...

Answer (score 0):

The for loop, but with a different syntax can as below seems to be [little more faster](http://jsperf.com/so-30228858)(in chome & IE)

```
function convert3(obj) {
    var ret = {}, arr;
    for (var key in obj) {
        arr = ret[obj[key]];
        if (!arr) {
            arr = ret[obj[key]] = [];
        }
        arr.push(key)
    }
    return ret;
}
```