# Loopback query - how to group by?

Tags: loopbackjs

Is there any way to perform a group by filter?
Something like the following:

```
 model.find({groupBy: 'myField'})
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hi, I don't think there is. I would use standard javascript to then group by a property of your returned array of elements, something like what's discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887900/group-objects-by-property-in-javascript

Comment: @MarcosMaia This could affect the performance over a huge amount of elements returned. It would be better to create the query your self, and extend the Model.

Comment: One problem with `GROUP BY` is that such queries usually do not return a structure fitting the model, so one would need a new model for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html) you can execute Native SQL queries however, we have no updates about this if its still works or not as they said :

> Warning: This feature has not been fully tested and is not officially
>   supported: the API may change in future releases. In general, it is
>   always better to perform database actions through connected models.
>   Directly executing SQL may lead to unexpected results, corrupted data,
>   and other issues.

For datasources > 1.x

```
dataSource.connector.execute(sql_stmt, params, callback);
```

or =< 1.x

```
dataSource.connector.query(sql_stmt, params, callback);
```

**1.sql_stmt - The SQL string.**

**2.params - parameters to the SQL statement.**

If you have a parametrized query like :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = $1 or SOMETHING = $2
```

Params will be : `params = [358, "SOMETHING"];`

**3.callback - callback function**

**4.Example**

```
module.exports = function (Collection) {    
    var ds = Collection.dataSource;
    var sql = "SELECT _id FROM table GROUP BY my_field;";
    var params = []; // = null (could be null also)

    ds.connector.execute(sql, params, function (err, data) {

        if (err) console.error(err);

        console.log(data);

    });    
};
```

if `query` or `execute` doesn't work try with `executeSQL`