# Object in an array got modified after a push

Tags: javascript, arrays

I stumbled upon this code when searching for an efficient javascript groupBy methods

```
  function transformArr(orig) {
        var newArr = [],
            types = {},
            i, j, cur;
        for (i = 0, j = orig.length; i < j; i++) {
            cur = orig[i];
            if (!(cur.type in types)) {
                types[cur.type] = {type: cur.type, foods: []};
                newArr.push(types[cur.type]);
            }
            types[cur.type].foods.push(cur.food);
        }
        return newArr;
    }
```

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15888145/2527122

As you can see from the code above, The newArr.push() is called only when the types array is empty.

My question is when

```
types[cur.type].foods.push(cur.food);
```

is called, the foods array inside the elements of newArray got modified as well.

I'm finding this control flow confusing as there are no more pushes called for newArray after `types` was filled.

Can anyone please help me explain why this is the case?

*This is my first StackOverflow question so sorry for any confusions*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `types` and `newArr` reference the same objects (containing the same `foods` array). `types` holds references by `type`, `newArr` by integer indices. But the reference will lead to the same object in memory. So it doesn't matter how you access this object either by `types[cur.type]` or by `newArr[someIndex]` you will get exactly the same object.

If you modify the array using `push` and then access it via reference you will notice modified array.

Effectively it is the same as

```js
var a = [];

var b = {refToArray: a}; // reference the same array
var c = [a]; // reference the same array

// if you do
a.push(1); // or b.refToArray.push(1), c[0].push(1)

// then when you access the array via b property
// you still get the same array
console.log(b.refToArray)

// same via c index
console.log(c[0])

// because
console.log(a === b.refToArray, a === c[0], b.refToArray === c[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! By reference was my first suspicion as well. Your code made it much clearer.