# How to make a new object from another one?

Tags: javascript

I have bunch of data being read from API and then I want to sort it out on frondend side in React.

The data that I have looks like this:

```
[{"project":4,"name":"X","id":0},
{"project":4,"name":"X","id":1},
{"project":4,"name":"X","id":2},
{"project":4,"name":"X","id":3},
{"project":4,"name":"Y","id":0}, 
{"project":4,"name":"Y","id":1},
{"project":4,"name":"Y","id":2}]
```

How I need it to look like is:

```
{name: "X", id: 0,1,2,3}
{name: "Y", id: 0,1,2}
```

I have tried groupby, loop, but they don't work as intended.

Comment: how did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group objects by property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887900/group-objects-by-property-in-javascript)

Comment: Iterate your data and for each key get its parsed key which is not in string format.

Comment: @Ramesh I tried the "groupby" from Lodash, but I ended up with name being the key, while all other info would fall in the value (both id and project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const original = [
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 0 },
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 1 },
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 2 },
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 3 },
  { project: 4, name: 'Y', id: 0 },
  { project: 4, name: 'Y', id: 1 },
  { project: 4, name: 'Y', id: 2 },
]

const result = []

original.forEach(v => {
  const item = result.find(o => o.name === v.name)
  if (!item) result.push({ name: v.name, id: [v.id] })
  else item.id.push(v.id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 0 },
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 1 },
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 2 },
  { project: 4, name: 'X', id: 3 },
  { project: 4, name: 'Y', id: 0 },
  { project: 4, name: 'Y', id: 1 },
  { project: 4, name: 'Y', id: 2 }
]

let newArr = []

arr.forEach(element => {
  let tmp = {}
  if (element.name && element.id) {
    tmp = {
      name: element.name,
      id: element.id
    }
    this.newArr.push(tmp)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Didnt work with 'this' so I tried removing it. The result is same as I used to get. it makes 6 new objects with name and Id.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very specific, and you are probably best doing some research using the link suggested in the comments of your question.

```js
let data = [
  {"project":4,"name":"X","id":0},
  {"project":4,"name":"X","id":1},
  {"project":4,"name":"X","id":2},
  {"project":4,"name":"X","id":3},
  {"project":4,"name":"Y","id":0}, 
  {"project":4,"name":"Y","id":1},
  {"project":4,"name":"Y","id":2}
];

let x = {name: "X", id: data.filter(v => v.name == "X").map(v => v.id)};
let y = {name: "Y", id: data.filter(v => v.name == "Y").map(v => v.id)};
```